# function that does not return any clear answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to figure out how exactly functions work in relation to integer use, and it seems that my code will not return an answer, Am I missing something that is key to the completion of the code

```
def removeEven(listofint):
    oddlist=[]
    for n in listofint:
        if(n%2==1):
            oddlist.append(n)
    return oddlist
removeEven([8,3,11,5,2,21,38,1,7])
```

Comment: Unindent `return oddlist`.

Comment: I did, it changed nothing, should I reprogram my code

Comment: Also replace last line with: `print(removeEven([8,3,11,5,2,21,38,1,7]))`

Comment: Get the return out of the loop

Comment: I feel so dumb, I am so sorry for wasting your time with something so trivial, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
def removeEven(listofint):
    oddlist=[]
    for n in listofint:
        if(n%2==1):
            oddlist.append(n)
    return oddlist
```

`removeEven([8,3,11,5,2,21,38,1,7])`

After indenting the code properly, it worked for me.